# `push_back` vs. `emplace_back` sign warning

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, compiler-warnings

I noticed when using Apple's clang - release (703.0.31) - that pushing a `[signed] int` onto a `std::vector<unsigned int>` via the `push_back` method would raise a warning about implicit sign conversion. I was satisfied with this, given the warning flags, but surprised that replacing it with the `emplace_back` method did not produce a warning.

I tested this with [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/ZY6VAF), and clang 3.9.0 exhibits the same behaviour. [gcc 6.2](https://godbolt.org/g/RkQZkh) does not produce a warning in either case.

Since an implicit sign conversion diagnostic is not (AFAIK) required behaviour, I would hesitate to call it a bug, but I am curious if I'm overlooking some edge case that explains (or complicates!) the exhibited behaviour.

Comment: What's your question? Is it why `emplace_back` doesn't produce a warning while `push_back` does? Or is it why clang emits a warning in the first place?

Comment: That's why you don't generally want to use emplacement semantics. Emplacement is about explicit conversions, meaning that *you* promise that the element can be constructed from your args with the intended result. If you have an existing value, use insertion, not emplacement. Example: `std::vector<std::chrono::seconds> time_to_missile_launch; time_to_missile_launch.emplace(15);`

Comment: A second reason for the (lack of) warning is that with push_back, the conversion happens at the call site, while with emplace_back, it happens inside a system header, which usually disables warnings.

Comment: @MarcGlisse - I hadn't considered this. Both clang and gcc appear to use: `#pragma GCC system_header` in their std lib headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's like the difference between this:

```
signed a = 0;
unsigned b = a;
```

And this:

```
unsigned b = unsigned(a);
```

The latter is a typical way to stop such warnings from happening (the other way would be a cast).

It's exactly the same when you call `emplace_back()` - the entire point of this method is to *construct* a `value_type` (unsigned in your case) from the given value.

Similarly, if you have:

```
struct Foo { explicit Foo(int x) {} };
```

Then you can do this:

```
std::vector<Foo> v;
v.emplace_back(1);
```

But not this:

```
v.push_back(1);
```

In summary, the meaning of `emplace_back()` is not "push_back() but more efficient."  Instead, it is "construct a value_type using these arguments, inside the container."

Comment: *"the other way would be a cast"* well, `unsigned(a)` *is* a cast, isn't it?